# Drop empty categories in sub groups using groupby in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a resulting table

```
Year  mycat
2019  A        2
      B        1
2020  A        0
      B        1
```

In the 3rd row (`2020, A`) you see zero. I want to get rid of lines like this.

```
Year  mycat
2019  A        2
      B        1
2020  B        1
```

How can I do this? Is there a way to let pandas handle that without "hacking" the resulting table after I've done `.groupby().size()`?

Here is the full code:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': [2019, 2019, 2019, 2020], 'mycat': list('AABB')})
>>> df.mycat = df.mycat.astype('category')

>>> df
   Year mycat
0  2019     A
1  2019     A
2  2019     B
3  2020     B

>>> df.groupby(['Year', 'mycat']).size()
Year  mycat
2019  A        2
      B        1
2020  A        0
      B        1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to eliminate zero-instance groupby results even for Categoricals such as in your specified input dataframe:

```py
df.groupby(['Year', 'mycat'], observed=True).size()
```

In the docs for [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), the `observed` argument is explained as follows:

> observed : bool, default False
>
> This only applies if any of the groupers are Categoricals. If True: only show observed values for categorical groupers. If False: show all values for categorical groupers.